# Some weird thing in python code, map() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
arr = map(int, input().split())

for i in arr:
    print(i)

print(list(arr)[1])
```

When I run this code and give the input as,

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

it gives the output as follows,

```
1
2
3
4
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muyustan/PycharmProjects/openCV/split.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(list(arr)[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then,

```
arr = map(int, input().split())

# for i in arr:
#     print(i)

print(list(arr)[1])
```

after commenting out the for loop and running the program and providing the same input, it gives the output at the terminal as follows;

```
2
```

Why using that for loop makes any changes?

Comment: Because you've exhausted that iterator by looping over it and `list(arr)` returned an empty list.

Comment: `map` doesn't return a list, it returns a map-object.

Comment: @ayhan türk müsün reis :d, neyse konsepti bozmayalım. Do iterators have something like a life span? When you iterate over them, do they vanish?

Comment: @thejborn but I convert it to list?

Comment: @muyustan not at the right place, see my answer.

Comment: You did convert it to a list by using `list()`, but you must do that before you iterate over it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had printed `arr` before the line of the exception, you'd have seen:

```
c:\srv\tmp> py3 weirdmap.py
1 2 3 4 5
<map object at 0x03611770>
2
```

the map-object is an iterator (that you can iterate over exactly once).

You could fix your code by either using a list comprehension:

```
arr = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
```

or by converting the iterator to a list before doing anything else with it:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

to see what is going on in the last line, consider this re-write:

```
mapobj = map(int, input().split())
arr = list(mapobj)
print(arr[2])         # <=== return the 3rd element
print(mapobj[2])      # <=== TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

changing the last line to

```
print(list(mapobj)[2])   # <=== IndexError: list index out of range
```

since the `arr = list(mapobj)` used up the iterator.

Comment: Thanks!, does the conversion(to list) process kills iterator arr right at that moment?

Comment: Yes, se updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Map function doesn't return a list but an iterator.
To obtain a list

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

You can only loop once over an iterator. 
When you write

```
arr = map(int, input().split())
```

No operations are made, you need to call the **next**() method over arr to obtain the next item. For loop does that.

Comment: thanks, so, while I convert it to a list with the first line of code in your answer, does the conversion process kills iterator arr right at there?

Comment: Yes, the iterator is "killed"